# Stylesheet (CSS) is not loading in my Sails application

Tags: css, node.js, sails.js, stylesheet, ejs

I've placed a style sheet `style.css` inside the `/assets/styles`-folder and embedded it via `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">` in my something.ejs file.

But the stylesheet is not loading. Has anyone an idea?

Comment: Are .ejs file and .css file in same folder?

Comment: no both are in seperate folder

Comment: It's basic. You must to write the correct path to your stylesheet. For example: /assets/styles/style.css

Comment: Then in href, use the complete path of css.

Comment: yeah i tried but its not working

Comment: Can you tell me your folder structure?

Comment: Folder where .ejs file is present?

Comment: Make sure that the paths to the css are correct and cache is not in action.

Comment: 'Employee/assets/styles' -style sheet location 'Employee/views/Employee'- ejs location

Comment: and where is your .ejs file?

Comment: 'Employee/views/Employee'- ejs location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following to give the correct location of style sheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/styles/style.css" type="text/css">
```

The first `..` will take it to `views` folder, the next `..` will take it to parent folder `Employees`, now you can give the path to your stylesheet.

This is because the path must always be relative to current `.ejs` or some other current file's location in the directory.

Comment: thank you for your effort. Its working when the tag is like this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../styles/style.css" type="text/css">`. without `/assets` and I placed a copy of `/styles` folder inside this `Employee/views/` folder